# How to access a component bound to a property in QML

Tags: qml

It's come up several times that I have wanted to access a property of a component which is bound to another property. I've spent days trying to figure out how to do this and failed. Below is a simple example of what I'm trying to do.

```
TabView {
  Component.onCompleted: console.log(style.frameOverlap)
  // OR tvStyle.frameOverlap

  style: TabViewStyle {
    id: tvStyle
    frameOverlap: 5
  }
}
```

Nothing like this works. I'm completely baffled about how to access these members either statically or as an instance. Can someone please explain to me whether something like this is possible?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do once you have access to it?

Comment: Hmm usually just to read one of the properties in order to adjust another visual element's size. For example, today I was trying to get the height of the tab buttons, TabViewStyle.tab.height.

Comment: Do you provide a complete `TabViewStyle`? E.g. do you assign all of the properties that you wish to access? If so, you can define the properties like `frameOverlap` in the "outer" scope and have your style refer to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you need to write:

```
Component.onCompleted: console.log(__styleItem.frameOverlap)
```

The longer answer is that the 'style' property is a Component. Component is something that remembers a tree of declarations, and can create objects as needed. However, it does not expose that remembered declaration, so when you try to access the `frameOverlap` property, it's not there.

In theory, you can call `style.createObject` to create an object, and examine its properties, but that would create another unnecessary instance, so you can look at TabView.qml, notice that it creates an instance already using Loader, and stores that in a property called `__styleItem`, and so use the code I gave above.

Of course, accessing internal properties is not a particularly good idea, but might be OK in practice. Ideally, one should be able to instantiate TabViewStyle and bind the instance to the `style` property, with TabView figuring out whether it's Component or object, but I'm not sure it's possible.

Comment: This should note that it's a "private", internal property that could change with any release (although I'd say that it's unlikely it will).

Comment: True, I've expanded the answer.